# jQuery - DataTables - How to get clicked row data - .Net 6 MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've followed various examples but not found a solution yet. I have a MVC Web App, the data tables is loaded within a partial view (which then calls `instantiateDataTable`). I am adding my JS code to get the clicked row data in the view that called this partial view.

I have tried something like this, but both console.logs are coming back as undefined.

```
   $('#resultsGrid tbody').on('click', function() {
      var row = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
      //for row data
      //console.log(table.row(row).data().id);
      var data = $('resultsGrid').DataTable().row(this).data();
      console.log(row);
      console.log(data);
   });
```

See JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p2one80j/1/

Any advise on why my code isn't working? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myTable = $('#resultsGrid').DataTable( {
       
    } ); 
    $('#resultsGrid tbody tr').on('click', function() {
      var data = myTable.row(this).data();
      console.log(data);
   }); 
} );
```

Output:

> ["102", "A name", "222 The Street", "A City", "IL", "90210", ""]

> ["100", "A Name", "123 The Street", "A City", "IL", "90210", ""]